# Images not displayed on Android emulator for phonegap/jquerymobile app

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, android-emulator

I'm developing a PhoneGap application with jQuery Mobile, and for some reason the jQuery mobile images are not displayed in the emulator or when deployed to a phone. Yet when running the site locally with a web browser, they work fine?

This is my first time using Eclipse (and hopefully my last to be honest). Is there something that I'm missing?

Folder structure

[image: folder structure]

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Emulator:
[image: emulator]

Comment: Are the images on a localhost server? If so, localhost means something different to the Android device - it means itself - not your machine.

Comment: The images are just in a folder referenced by the jquery.mobile.css

Comment: (see update for folder structure)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surprisingly, this was caused because css image references are case sensitive on the devices. Renaming the 'Images' folder to 'images' fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you used an Image with CMYK Color Mode with 32 bit, then your Image won't display.
To solve this problem use the PNG Images or RGB Color Mode at all.